# Catching socket create events in Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

My goal is to monitor traffic generated by a process. The approach that i was thinking of was to handle each socket create event for that process and based on that create a new rule in IPTables. Once the process terminates i can compute the data transferred by it.

I can find out all the open sockets of a process by using netstat but that results in poor performance as i have to poll netstat after fixed intervals, to check if any new socket has been opened by this process. I want to use some interrupt based mechanism.

Is there a way by which my application can get notified whenever a new socket is created in the system?